# Password handling in Apache to remote LDAP server

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap

I have an Apache server in which I have a website with a protected directory.  Protected by basic authentication against a remove LDAP server (not on same machine).

```
<Location  "/mywebapp/myprotected">
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
AuthType basic
AuthName "Enter your credentials"
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap.differentserver.org:3268/dc=company,dc=org?sAMAccountName?sub?(&(objectCategory=*)(objectClass=user))"
Require valid-user
AuthLDAPBindDN 'cn="Adminaccount,OU=Service IDs,OU=Application IDs,OU=Support,OU=Administration,dc=company,dc=org'
AuthLDAPBindPassword adminpassword
</Location>
```

This set is currently working.  All connections are plain text.

What I don't understand is why don't I see my password in wireshark when the apache server interacts with the ldap.differentserver.org.  I see my password when I enter it in the popup dialog box on its way to the web server, but not from the web server to the ldap server.   I do see the AuthLDAPBindPassword.

In wireshark, the only protocols I see are TCP, DNS, LDAP, HTML.  I do not see any TLS protocol messages so I'm assuming that the LDAP server is not stepping up to TLS.

I see the LDAP search message on my username in plain text but my password doesn't seem to be in any of the messages.

The system *IS* working - I would just like an explanation of how LDAP is getting my normal user password because I don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

I found it.  It is encoded has hex bytes.

Comment: You should register an account, so that you can take ownership of your questions and answers here.

Answer (score 0):

Ldap stores passwords as hashes. (ie encrypted). Without going into technical details of the interactions between mod_authz and ldap... Apache checks the hash of the password you supplied at the login window with the hash that is stored in ldap.

As an aside: You should do all authentication of https with apache for the very reason that you have observed: Anyone can sniff your traffic and see your plaintext password.

Comment: While an LDAP server may store a password as a hash it may also store it in plaintext, obfuscated text or a pointer to another authentication mechanism (or all of the above). `mod_authz` does not attempt to compare the hashes but rather attempts bind with the provided credentials. This should be especially clear in the provided example as Active-Directory provides no mechanism to read any form of a users password via `LDAP`. While your aside is correct, having Apache operate on HTTPS would not limit the unencrypted LDAP bind on the backend, which requires LDAPS, LDAP starttls.